# what's causing the android preview error in Xamarin forms for the tabbed page XAML file?

Tags: xamarin.forms, preview

I am new to Xamarin, following a tutorial to make a tabbed page within an app, when trying to see the preview of a tabbed page, it works fine on iOS preview but on android preview it says "an exception occurred while rendering the control"
further more, if I click the flag on the right I see this :

**image capture of error logs**

[image]

the app complies and runs as expected on both iOS / Android simulators
preview of mainpages is fine, it's just the tabbed page preview that's showing this error on android.

here is the xaml code for the page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1"
            x:Class="App1.homePage">
    <local:HistoryPage Title="History"/>
    <local:MapPage Title="Map"/>
    <local:ProfilePage Title="Profile"/>

</TabbedPage>
```

Comment: What is the version of your IDE?

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 for Mac  version 8.2.6 ( build 26 )

Comment: Check if you had installed the android sdk support in your mac.

Comment: on tools -> SDK Manager i have the following installed :  https://imgur.com/a/3DxzvpQ .     , also i have updated today the visual studio to the following version : https://imgur.com/a/Ri6kiw1

Comment: You can report the issue : Help ->Report a problem .

Comment: thanks lucas, i have reported the issue as you suggested. the issue is still appearing in the latest update of visual studio 2019 for mac 8.3 build 1805

Comment: Did you test it on vs for windows?

Comment: yes it works on visual studio community 2019 on windows 10, just copied the app to my laptop and i can see the preview on the tabbed page. I guess it's a bug limited to the Mac version.